# How to call and execute multiple Jsonresult functions get response asynchronously from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GetData('../Layout/GetData');
    GetData('../Layout/GetDataOne');
});

function GetData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            name: "test name"
        },
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function() {}
    });
}

public JsonResult GetData(string name) {
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    TestModel model = new Testmodel();
    model = GetDataresult(name);
    result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    result = Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return result;
}

public JsonResult GetDataOne(string name) {
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    TestModel model = new Testmodel();
    model = GetDataresultSet(name);
    result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    result = Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return result;
}
```

While Calling ajax from those two methods call is hitting first to GetData(string name) and not executing second ajax method simultaneously , and it is waiting for first ajax response then hitting the second ajax call.

I need to hit two JsonResult functions at a time and get the response asynchronously..

Comment: How are you asserting that they are *not* simultaneous?  What are you using server-side?   VS "http"?  IIS? IIS which version?  etc    It might be that your server is configured to only accept one request at a time - so would need to know the server details.

Comment: Actually it's  a MVC application using VS 2019 version. I am not sure how to configure server configuration.. Can i have more details of server configuration.